# Why we don't use such URL formats?

Tags: url, url-routing, friendly-url

I am reworking on the URL formats of my project. The basic format of our search URLs is this:-

```
www.projectname/module/search/<search keyword>/<exam filter>/<subject filter>/... other params ...
```

On searching with no search keyword and exam filter, the URL will be :-

```
www.projectname/module/search///<subject filter>/... other params ...
```

My question is why don't we see such URLs with back to back slashes (3 slashes after www.projectname/module/search)? Please note that I am not using .htaccess rewrite rules in my project anymore. This URL works perfect functionally. So, should I use this format?

For more details on why we chose this format, please check my other question:-
[Suggest best URL style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218130/suggest-best-url-style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web servers will typically remove multiple slashes before the application gets to see the request,for a mix of compatibility and security reasons. When serving plain files, it is usual to allow any number of slashes between path segments to behave as one slash.

Blank URL path segments are not invalid in URLs but they are typically avoided because relative URLs with blank segments may parse unexpectedly. For example in `/module/search`, a link to `//subject/param` is not relative to the file, but a link to the server `subject` with path `/param`.

Whether you can see the multiple-slash sequences from the original URL depends on your server and application framework. In CGI, for example (and other gateway standards based on it), the `PATH_INFO` variable that is typically used to implement routing will usually omit multiple slashes. But on Apache there is a non-standard environment variable `REQUEST_URI` which gives the original form of the request without having elided slashes or done any %-unescaping like `PATH_INFO` does. So if you want to allow empty path segments, you can, but it'll cut down on your deployment options.

There are other strings than the empty string that don't make good path segments either. Using an encoded `/` (%2F), `\` (%5C) or null byte (%00) is blocked by default by many servers. So you can't put any old string in a segment; it'll have to be processed to remove some characters (often ‘slug’-ified to remove all but letters and numbers). Whilst you are doing this you may as well replace the empty string with `_`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because it's not clearly defined whether or not the extra / should be ignored or not.

For instance: http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport and http://news.bbc.co.uk//////////sport both display the same page in Firefox and Chrome. The server is treating the two urls as the same thing, whereas your server obviously does not.

I'm not sure whether this behaviour is defined somewhere or not, but it does seem to make sense (at least for the BBC website - if I type an extra /, it does what I meant it to do.)